# How do I show a NetSuite Content Delivery Page in SuiteCommerce Denali or Mont Blanc

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

I'm working with NetSuite SuiteCommerce Mont Blanc.

I've got my website setup locally.

I've installed the Content Delivery Service bundle and created a test landing page called 'Test' with a url '/Test'.

I tried to view the test page using this url:

/sca-dev-montblanc/shopping-local.ssp#Test

It's not found, what did I miss?

I also tried deploying it and using the urls

/sca-dev-montblanc/Test & /Test

Still not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an answer...

You don't.

You use the new Site Management Tools instead.

Answer (score 0):

/sca-dev-montblanc/Test & /Test..... In this you are not using your Netsuite account ID and domain name itself then how it will work.So please Add your Account ID and domain name then try
  For Example

www.Munish.com/c.TSTDRV00000123/sca-dev-montblanc/shopping.ssp?n=4

try out like this definitely it will work.I am using the same way for my SCA denali

Comment: I can see the site, I just couldn't see any content pages.